# r rms error using validate

Tags: r, rms

I'm building an Linear model using OLS in the r package with:

```
model<-ols(nallSmells ~ rcs(size, 5) + rcs(minor,5)+rcs(change_churn,3)
+rcs(review_rate,0), data=quality,x=T, y=T)
```

When I want to validate my model using:
    `validate(model,B=100)`

I get the following error:

```
Error in lsfit(x, y) : only 0 cases, but 2 variables
In addition: Warning message:
In lsfit(x, y) : 1164 missing values deleted
```

But if I decrease B, e.g., B=10, I works. Why I can't iterate more.  Also I notice that the seed has an effect when I use this method.
Can someone give me some advice?

UPDATE:

I'm using rcs(review_rate,0) because I want to assign the 0 number of knots to this predictor, according to my DOF budget.  I noticed that the problem is with thte data in review_rate. Even if I ommit the parameter in rcs() and just put the name of the predictor, I get errors.  This is the frequency of the data in review_rate: `count(quality$review_rate)
          x freq
1 0.8571429    1
2 0.9483871    1
3 0.9789474    1
4 0.9887640    1
5 0.9940476    1
6 1.0000000 1159`  I wonder if there is a relationship with the values of this vector? Because when I built the OLS model, I get the following warning:

```
Warning message:
In rcspline.eval(x, nk = nknots, inclx = TRUE, pc = pc, fractied = fractied) :
5 knots requested with 6 unique values of x.  knots set to 4 interior values.
```

The values in the other predictors are real positives, but if ommit review_rate predictor I don't get any warning or error.

Thanks for your support.

I add the link for a sample of 100 of my data for replication

https://www.dropbox.com/s/oks2ztcse3l8567/examplestackoverflow.csv?dl=0

X represent the depedent variable and Y4 the predictor that is giving me problems.

```
require (rms)
Data <- read.csv ("examplestackoverflow.csv")
testmodel<-ols(X~ rcs(Y1)+rcs(Y2)+rcs(Y3),rcs(Y4),data=Data,x=T,y=T)
validate(testmodel,B=1000)
```

Kind regards,

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample data and code that we can copy and paste into R to recreate the error.

Comment: Not yet reproducible but it was surprising to see `rcs(review_rate,0)`. Is that what you meant to put in. I'm not sure how that would work. Your intent would be more clear if you named your parameters.

Comment: I'm using rcs(review_rate,0) because I want to assign the 0 number of knots to this predictor, according to my DOF budget.  I noticed that the problem is with thte data in review_rate. Even if I ommit the parameter in rcs() and just put the name of the predictor, I get errors.  This is the frequency of the data in review_rate: